# Why are ardor transactions called via the api not in chronological order by timestamp?

Tags: ardor

When retrieving data from the Ardor api, why is the data returned not in chronological order?

[image]

Comment: Which API call are you doing exactly? It's supposed to be in reverse chronological order: https://nxtwiki.org/wiki/The_Nxt_API#Get_All_Tagged_Data

Comment: searchTaggedData

Comment: It's not in any order it seems: https://prnt.sc/l4ln1k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The results are first ordered by the [score which Apache Lucene assigns to them](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/package-summary.html#scoring) . If two results get same score, they are ordered by `blockTimestamp`, descending (what happens with the 2nd, 3rd and 4th result in your data).

Apache Lucene is configured with the default [BM25Similarity](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/BM25Similarity.html) with parameters k1 = 1.2 b = 0.75, i.e. Ardor uses the default scoring function. More details about that function can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25). The query parser is configured with [default operator](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_1_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParserBase.html#setDefaultOperator-org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.Operator-) `AND`, so if your query contains two words, they must both be present in order for the data to be included in the result

Answer (score 1):

From petko:

They are ordered by `ScoreDoc.score` - see https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_2_1/core/index.html?org/apache/lucene/search/ScoreDoc.html